# Decimation glitch for ratio < 0.2

Tags: modifiers

I'm having trouble with decimation.

I have a mesh of a head. I wish to decimate to 10%, whilst keeping the ears at 100%.

So I create a Vertex group for each ear, and a third vertex group called foo for the remaining vertices.

[image]

It is this foo group I wish to decimate:

[image]

So far this is good, but if I lower the ratio below 0.3 it goes wonky:

[image]

Well, I almost have what I need. If I apply the same decimation again, that should reduce the detail sufficiently.  i.e. 30% * 30% = 9% ~ 0.1 which is what I was after.  But applying it twice, the second application gives another wonky picture the same as the one I posted.

Also, I shouldn't have to be sidestepping around weird behaviour I don't understand. Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

PS I guess I can manually create a new Vertex group and decimate that...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly. Does the model decrease in detail/faces between .3 and 0? If not, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Hey, just FYI. [Signatures and taglines are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).

Answer (score 3):

The ratio on the decimate modifier doesn't refer to level detail, it refers to the number of faces. From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Decimate#Options):

> *Ratio*: The ratio of faces to keep after decimation, from 0.0 (0%, all faces have been completely removed) to 1.0 (100%, mesh is completely
>   intact, except quads have been triangulated). 
>       As the percentage drops from 1.0 to 0.0, the mesh becomes more and more decimated until it no longer visually looks like the original
>   mesh.